# What are the notable differences between Hunter x Hunter in 1999 vs 2011?

Tags: hunter-x-hunter

[*Hunter × Hunter*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hunter_%C3%97_Hunter) is quite a large series which has [an anime starting in 1999](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hunter_%C3%97_Hunter_(1999_TV_series)) and [one starting in 2011](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Hunter_%C3%97_Hunter_(2011)_episodes). The latter is longer (currently at 80 episodes versus 62 from the original), and is said to follow the manga more faithfully.

[image: A few of the Hunter x Hunter characters~]

I have not read the manga, nor seen either series. What are the major differences* in these two adaptations?

<sub>* - Minor differences need not be stated, only ones which affect plot or character development significantly.</sub>

Answer (score 19):

I'm a Japanese, so please excuse my English.

I ignore a lot of small changes, and want to talk about the cause.

Speaking from the conclusion, the notable differences are the following, I think:

1. Original Manga's Progress
2. Broadcasting Station
3. Main Target

**1. Original Manga's Progress**

Togashi is working now. That's all.

**2. Broadcasting Station**

Fuji TV is following One Piece, Toriko and Dragon Ball.
It is the HxH 2009's station, and faithful to the original.
Fuji's slogan is "NO FUN, NO TV", and is known as the most vulgar TV station in Japan.
But I really, really love Fuji's "noitaminA".

The 2011's Nippon TV is the most traditional commercial broadcasting station.
This oldest station is known as the most aggressive technical pioneer.
Maybe the original fans hate their editing, and the children's parents like it.
I think that the 140 times same OP songs is their attempt, too.

**3. Main Target**

In Japan, HxH 2009 was the "Saturday Golden Time Anime"; then from episode 62 onward, it became OVA. HxH 2011 was the "Sunday Morning Anime"; then from episode 99 onward, it became "Midnight Anime". Both began broadcasting in time slots meant for "Children's Anime" in Japan,
and OVA and "Midnight Anime" were the "Adults' Anime".

The nature of the children's time slot is slightly different between the two continuities. "Saturday Golden Time Anime" means that children watch the anime with their parents at dinnertime.
"Golden Time TV Program" is the TV Program that airs between 18:00 ~ 20:00 in Japan.
If the Golden Time Anime airs on Saturdays, TV station is expecting the conversation with the children.
In other words, children logical conversation with the parent is satisfied are eligible.
This is why HxH 2009 did not refrain from grotesque representations, in contrast to HxH 2011. 
The reason why the TV broadcast was finished is because the original stock was gone.
By the way, there is no relation to the animation named "Golden Time".

On Sunday mornings, I think you are still sleeping, right?
In this time slot, most young children are watching TV, so a more wholesome animation is required.
Japanese parents do not like their children watching torn heads or hearts or fingers without supervision.
I think the reason of the change in time slot is that there are few parents who like their children watching torn organs in anime.
Then I wonder what kind of adult gets up in the early Sunday mornings, but I do not have the answer. I think they are probably also the type that does not turn on the TV during dinnertime.

Anyway, I do not write in detail because spoilers, but HxH 2011 thoroughly ignored the content of the original manga.
I'll never forgive the corruption related to Kite, the worst difference for me:

> In the original manga and the 2009 anime, the reason why Gon aimed to become a hunter is because Kite told him that Gon's father is a superior hunter. Gon thought his father was dead.
>  First appearance: Kite gave Gon a scolding "you should not come near the territory of dangerous organisms".
>
>  In the 2011 anime, Gon has forgotten the existence of Kite, and they don't know each other, not even the names.
>  First appearance: Kite had been fishing on the side of the nests of chimera ants.

For more information, you can read [this wiki](http://hunterxhunter.wikia.com/wiki/Kite#Anime_and_Manga_Differences).

Comment: I agree about Kite's regrettable lack of introduction early in the 2011 series.  While I prefer the 2011 overall, folks should watch the first two episodes of the 1999 series to really understand Kite and how he can mean so much to Gon.  The 2011 does offer a flashback to their first meeting soon after Gon and Killua teleport to him, but that flashback just doesn't have the same emotional impact.  Madhouse probably thought 75 episodes between Kite's introduction and reunion with him was too much, but they could have had Gon meet him in ep.1 and still had a flashback in ep.76.

Answer (score 5):

Besides the quality of the graphics, you've already said it, the 2011 version is more faithful in the manga.

Answer (score 5):

There are only minor differences between the old Hunter × Hunter and the new Hunter × Hunter.  The main reason they decided to do a remake was because of the viewer group. Almost no one would decide to pick up Hunter × Hunter if it were to start right in the middle after more than a 10-year break.

Answer (score 5):

Hunter × Hunter 2011 is the 'reboot' of the original series of 1999. It was created in order to improve the quality of the animation (ex. cute Bisky), and because the 1999 series was very popular; they rebooted the series to gain some more popularity. Also, the reboot completely follows the manga and reduces huge amount of fillers, like the Greed Island arc.

Answer (score 1):

the intro/outros are different.
 otherwise, *(I just watched all of the 1999v, and started w/the 2011, and could barely tell the difference...except)*
 the 2011 in/out theme is a bit obnoxious, while I'm partial to the 1999 version.

imo the 1999 ending song (with the female voice) is the best.
otherwise, I've watched all of the 1999v, and up to ep11 on the 2011v... with the verdict of the 2011v is a quicker story, and one youtube version (1-5 combined into one video) completely skips the first episode entirely.

one of my favorite parts was in the 1999v ep1, when Gon meets the fox-bear, and Kite, and this is a very touching part of the story that is left out of the 2011v. This sub-story also comes into play later on, and should be considered important..so, if you only watch the 2011v, then I recommend to (also, at least) watch the 1999v ep.1 as well to get a few extra bits of the story.

Answer (score 0):

The fillers, OMG the Fillers! Animation quality is better in new. Stuff regarding kite, see the wikia for story related differences they have a good list. Also the soundtrack has a noticeable difference.  Not that one soundtrack is better than the other, as the new one is pretty good. There were scenes I thought the 2009 soundtrack did better (just felt darker for some reason).

Kurapica vs Uvogin,
Phantom Troupe's assault on the Auction (when Chrollo conducts the music of war),
Pakunoda's death scene with the chains

Sidenote - Overall I prefer the new one minus the music parts listed above. (sadly i also really enjoyed some of the soundtrack of the original FMA even though FMA:Brotherhood was better overall.  I wish they would keep original music people enjoyed in these Anime remakes or integrated in a way that did homage to it)

Answer (score -1):

I think the 2011 version of *Hunter x Hunter* has better music cast and drawings than the 1999 version.

The story in the 1999 version stops in the middle, but the 2011 version continues until the end, although it has many fights, some sad moments, and happy ones.

Comment: Welcome to Anime.SE! This looks like just your own opinions on the two series, instead of looking at the objective differences between them.